# how to open url using telegram bot python code

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I was wondering how to open URL by pressing inlinekeyboard button with my telegram bot using python.
Based on documentation this is supposed to work

`button = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=False, resize_keyboard=True) button.row( telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Binance', url="my url") )`

but it is not and I can't figure out why?
any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"? What happens when you run the code and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?

Comment: hi Robert, I expect it to open my browser and return the website however it does nothing. I mean nothing happens when I press that button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to build a `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` but add an `InlineKeyboardButton` instead of a `ReplyKeyboardButton`, which is not supported. `ReplyKeyboardMarkups` are just shortcuts for sending predefined text messages and don't support opening URLs. See https://core.telegram.org/bots#keyboards.

Comment: Happy to hear :) Please consider marking my answer as accepted, then ;)